# Create View Programmatically in Objective-C Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, view, uiviewcontroller

How should I go about creating a View for the storyboard programmatically? I want to access the labels from the first ViewController object made(automatically to call the IBAction methods of VC). I know that this first object of VC is the one linked to the view in the storyboard(?) and I need to change a label form another file, besides VC. I'm pretty sure the only way to do so would be to access the VC object that is linked to the view, or create one and not go with the default one that is created. If not, how would I go about accessing the labels of the view from another file?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to do, maybe try to explain it a bit more in detail and with examples of the code or files your app consists of?

Comment: You also mention making a view programatically but you mention storyboard + ibaction. Generally you won't programatically make a view if you're using Storyboard/NIBs.

Comment: I want to make a view programmatically so I can change the labels from another file, besides VC. @MarkGibson . The program, I think, makes a VC object that links to the view, and I want to make this object myself so I can change the labels of it, which are linked to the view. Making another object of VC doesn't work to change the labels in the view, because the object I created is not linked to the view.

Comment: Changing the contents of a label from another class has nothing to do whether the view is made in IB or in code. You really shouldn't do that any way -- if you want to change the text, pass the new string to the controller that has the labels, and let that controller update its own UI.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create storyboard objects programmatically.  A storyboard is very basically an XML file Xcode uses to call different view controllers.  The biggest advantage of using storyboards over NIBs is you can layout transitions or segues, and the advantage of NIBs or storyboards over initiating view controllers by code is obviously the visual interface.  So your question doesn't really make sense.
If you want to reference a particular view controller's label from your storyboard you need to create a pointer to that view controller first, but changing it programmatically doesn't make sense because that's what storyboard is for.
That said you may just need to go look for your class name in your view controller's Identity Inspector in storyboard and then edit your label programmatically through an IBOutlet property.